# Why does numpy change the order of columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am reading data from EXCEL to a pandas `DataFrame`:

`df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='FactoidList', ignore_index=False, sort=False)`

Applying `sort=False` preserves the original order of my columns. But when I apply a numpy condition list, which generates a numpy array, the order of the columns changes.

Numpy orders the columns alphabetically from A to Z and I do not know how I can prevent it. Is there an equivalent to `sort=False`?

I searched online but could not find a solution. The problem is that I want to re-convert the numpy array to a dataframe in the original format, re-applying the original column names.

**ADDITION: code for condition list used in script:**

```
condlist = [f['pers_name'].str.contains('|'.join(qn)) ^ f['pers_name'].isin(qn),
                    f['inst_name'].isin(qi), 
                    f['pers_title'].isin(qt),
                    f['pers_function'].isin(qf),
                    f['rel_pers'].str.contains('|'.join(qr)) ^ f['rel_pers'].isin(qr)]

choicelist = [f['pers_name'], 
                     f['inst_name'], 
                     f['pers_title'],
                     f['pers_function'],
                     f['rel_pers']]

output = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
print(output) # this print output already shows an inversion of columns
rows=np.where(output)
new_array=f.to_numpy()
result_array=new_array[rows]
```

Comment: Please also post the relevant parts of the numpy code, since that's the part that seems to be causing the problem. Can you reproduce this without us needing an Excel sheet, just with a small example dataframe?

Comment: Also I don't see a `sort` option in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: I figured out that numpy isn't the problem at all but pandas itself. I have appended one dataframe where I explicitly stated `sort=False` to another one that had `sort=False`, but I made the wrong assumption that the combined dataframe would inherit this. Will post answer with code.

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing my script, I figured out that the problem isn't `numpy` but `pandas`.

Before applying my condition list, I am adding the dataframe `df` with the explicit `sort=False` statement to another dataframe `f` with the exact same structure, but I made the wrong assumption that the new combined dataframe would inherit `sort=False`.

Instead, I had to make it explicit:

`f = f.append(df, axis=1, ignore_index=False, sort=False)`